# Avoid right shift when starting a new line

Tags: floats

I have included many figures with this code:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\makebox[\linewidth]{       %        to center the image
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,scale=0.5]{stationary2_A75.eps}}
\captionof{figure}{$A=7.5$}
\end{minipage}
```

The problem is that the first row is shifted to the right compared with the rows below. 
I think it might have something to do with right shifting when I start a new line, so how can I avoid right hand shift with a new line? Or maybe it is something different?

Comment: `\noindent` at the beginning of the line, although I should point out that `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}` will not, in itself, center the line.

Comment: Thank you! What is a better way to center the line?

Comment: Never do `{ %` that pushes your image off center (even if you use \noindent` so the box isn't indented as you have a word space to the left of the image and not on the right.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, it does:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that.  Senior moment, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\makebox[\linewidth]{...}` makes only sense if your image is *wider* than `\linewidth`. If not, use

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{stationary2_A75}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{stationary2_A76}%
\caption{$A=7.5$}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I need to have two figures on one line, how can I do that then?

Comment: see myedited answer. Important is _no empty_ line between the two `\includegraphics`. That will be a new paragraph and the images will be upside down